# How to calculate Product of Sum (Array fields) in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

//Sample collection

```
db.grades.insertMany([{ _id: 1, quizzes: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
{ _id: 2, quizzes: [ ] },
{ _id: 3, quizzes: [ 3, 8, 9 ] }])
```

Below is the query i am using and getting results.
//Product of Sum

```
db.grades.aggregate(
   [
    { $project:
         { sumof:
            {
              $map:
                 {
                   input: "$quizzes",
                   as: "grade",
                   in: { $sum :[ "$$grade", "$$grade" ] }
                 }
            }
         }
      },

    {   $project :
        { "productOfSum":
            { $reduce :
                { input : '$sumof',
                    initialValue: 1,
                in : {$multiply :["$$value","$$this"]}
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    ]
)
```

The output of the query is as below.

```
{"_id":1,"productOfSum":48}
{"_id":2,"productOfSum":1}
{"_id":3,"productOfSum":1728}
```

Can any one advice how and why for **"_id:2"**, value is coming as ***1*** even though array is ***null***?

Comment: Because `initialValue` is `1`

Comment: however the array is null. Would multiplying a null array with 1, should it result with 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
db.grades.aggregate(
   [

```
{$project:
{quizzes:
    {$cond:
        [{$eq: [{$size: "$quizzes"}, 0]} , [0], "$quizzes"] } 
    }
 },

{ $project:
     { sumof:
        {
          $map:
             {
               input: "$quizzes",
               as: "grade",
               in: { $sum :[ "$$grade", "$$grade" ] }
             }
        }
     }
  },

{   $project :
    { "productOfSum":
        { $reduce :
            { input : '$sumof',
                initialValue: 1,
            in : {$multiply :["$$value","$$this"]}
            }
        }
    }
}   
]
```

)

Comment: You have to initialize empty arrays with 0 value

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most